# Como permitir apenas uma instancia de determinada classe?

Tags: python, singleton

Se executarmos o código abaixo, será criada uma janela com um botão dentro, que sempre que clicado irá abrir outra janela(Window2)... Como fazer para que não seja permitido uma segunda instancia de Window2? Quero fazer isso sem usar modal().

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gi.repository import Gtk

class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        button = Gtk.Button('Click')
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = 'Main Window')
        button.connect('clicked', Window2)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)
        self.add(button)
        self.show_all()

class Window2(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        button = Gtk.Button('Exit')
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = 'Window2')
        button.connect('clicked', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)
        self.add(button)
        self.show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: De uma lida nesse Design Pattern: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton assim você poderá adaptar seu código ao Singleton

Comment: @DiegoVieira Nesse caso particular, não creio que seja necessário usar singleton (basta o OP mudar o comportamento do botão), mas se quiser dar uma resposta cobrindo o caso geral, fique à vontade! (pelo título, é provável que essa pergunta atraia muitas visitas.. :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No caso geral, uma resposta é usar Singleton, como [apontado por Diego Vieira nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23121/como-permitir-apenas-uma-instancia-de-determinada-classe#comment42265_23121). No seu caso específico, creio que basta mudar o comportamento do botão para não criar uma janela toda vez:

```
class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window2 = None     # Cria-se uma referência no self para a janela

        button = Gtk.Button('Click')
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = 'Main Window')
        button.connect('clicked', self.mostrar_janela)    # Mostra-a quando clicar no botão
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)
        self.add(button)
        self.show_all()

    def mostrar_janela(self):
        if not self.window2:
            self.window2 = Window2()
        # else mostrar janela ?
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, desde que eu não feche a window2 pelo 'x' da janela. Se o fizer, quando clico outra vez no botão da primeira janela, window2 volta a abrir, mas vazia.

Comment: @user11647 Eu não tenho experiência com Gtk, então não posso te ajudar nos detalhes, mas o *workflow* que eu sugeriria é o seguinte: 1) crie a janela já no construtor, mas invisível; 2) quando se clicar no botão, mostre a janela; 3) na ação padrão ao fechar a janela (pelo 'x' ou por outros meios), escolha "esconder". Deve ter opções para isso na API, sugiro dar uma pesquisada.

Comment: A sugestão é boa, mas não é viável num programa com muitas janelas secundárias, e pelo pouco que aprendi até agora, janelas do tipo Top Level não podem ser ocultadas em Gtk, mas obrigado pela ajuda. Já me adiantou um bom caminho!

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução até que viável para a questão de permitir apenas uma instancia de determinada janela em Gtk

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gi.repository import Gtk

class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        button = Gtk.Button('Click')
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = 'Main Window')
        button.connect('clicked', self.run_window2)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)
        self.add(button)
        self.show_all()

    def run_window2(self, widget):
        try:
            #Chama a janela para frente, se a janela ainda não existe,
            #ocorre um AttributeError, passando então para o except e assim criando a janela. 
            self.window2.present()
        except:
            self.window2 = Window2()

class Window2(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        button = Gtk.Button('Exit')
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = 'Window2')
        button.connect('clicked', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)
        self.add(button)
        self.show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sem querer desmerecer as outras respostas e apesar de estarem corretas e resolverem o caso especifico, talvez de um jeito até melhor, também sem entrar em méritos se singleton é um bom padrão de projeto ou não a minha sugestão é para outros casos em geral.

**Como permitir apenas uma instância de determinada classe?**

Em outras palavras:

**Como criar um singleton em python?**

**Usando metaclasses:**

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Window(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
```

**Ou em Python 3**

```
class Window(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

E finalmente se você quiser que `__init__` seja chamado toda vez que a classe é chamada adicione:

```
    else:
        cls._instances[cls].__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

fonte: inspirado descaradamente de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python

Comment: Não acho que metaclasse seja uma boa forma de criar singletons. Só o método `__new__` de classes normais resolve bem - e você não tem problema de conflito de metaclasses.